# Using a Sharepoint Workflow to trigger a Java Class?

Tags: java, class, events, sharepoint, workflow

I am creating a SharePoint Workflow using the 2013 version and want it so that if any change is made to a particular item in a SharePoint List, the changed item(or entire data set) is sent to a Java class where it can then be used. Is this possible to even do this, and if not, what would be a workaround to achieve this result?

With Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible.

The best thing, we can call service through workflow or even handler (Item created). This service can be in java.

Thanks

Comment: Thanks for your response. How can I go about calling a web service from the workflow?

Comment: are you using workflow Manager for SharePoint 2013? If yes, then you have a activity, "Call HTTP Service" . If your workflow Manager is not configure than you need to add utility. Go to link please http://ilovesharepoint.codeplex.com/